# Number of items in skeleton loader

Tags: response-time

I have a list of users. When the list is first loaded a skeleton list is presented, so that the user will experience a (perceived) performance boost:
https://github.com/ksux/ks-design-guide/issues/38
[image: loader]

What would be a good number of items in the skeleton, if some customers may have 5 users, and some may have 2,000?

Comment: I would say that showing a skeleton for something that is unknown is confusing (why show e.g. 6 items when a second later there are 3, or 30?). I think another approach altogether would be more appropriate here. Or talk to the devs, maybe they can provide the number of items in advance?

Comment: On the back end, couldn't you efficiently index each customer's user count? So that you *do* know the number of users very quickly/up front, and then you do the longer query/load to actually load the users and metadata?

Comment: @JosefEngelfrost facebook are doing exactly that..

Comment: @J.Dimeo assume there's no solution through code here..

Comment: @NirSmadar note that facebook is doing this with an infinite list/scroll--which would be a bit different than a finite list of users.

Comment: Be weary of what you think is a gain. Personally when Facebook is taking its time to load and shows me the skeleton list it reminds me that it is slow and that I am staring at nothing. I'd argue that a small spinner for new stuff above a rendered list of stuff it already had loaded for my timeline would be better... Letting me see actual content.

Answer (score 1):

*Assumption:* You are talking about a results list that does not live on a separate page (full page experience) and I am assuming this is some sort of search or auto complete type of a feature.

**What I learned:**

In the studies I've done, a magic number for a list is between 5 and 9. If you display less than 5 users don't mind seeing more and after 9 information quickly becomes overwhelming.

### Your example:

**Short Answer:**
Best practice is to display a spinner (animated image) and/or a label "loading results" or something similar to notify a user that the process is still preparing results.

**Long Answer:**
Showing a skeleton is ONLY going to be helpful if you know you would have to display 100 results and you display 100 skeleton items. If the number of skeleton / placeholder items does not match the number of items in the result - it will raise more questions from the user stand point.

- Why did I see 10 and all of a sudden that changes to 3, where did the other 7 go?
- If I saw 3 placeholder items and now I see a 100, where did these extra items come from? Did i make a mistake in my search query?

[image]

Also, as a side note, if a user is searching for something and they find 2000 results, they most likely wont go through all 2000, unless they ned to do a mass action of some sort. Paginating that list or breaking results into smaller groups is recommended to keep the load times shorter and page weight smaller.

Comment: "...magic number for a list is between 5 and 9." Aha! It's [Miller's "7±2" theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two)!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend in this case displaying the users as they become available, with a label like "Loading more users..." appearing below the last user that disappears when the last user is loaded. MS Outlook does this when searching email- it presents a blank screen with the text "Searching..." and then as emails are found, they begin to populate downward.

(Unless that's not possible either- it's all or nothing- you don't know the first user's data until you've loaded all users' data)